# How to pass parameters to JasperReport with java to use later in SQL query

Tags: java, parameters, jasper-reports

I already have 6 Jasper Report templates created, with all of the static text fields to be filled out using a SQL query. The SQL query uses 2 parameters that I am passing in: **FirstName** and **LastName**. I am also passing in 2 other parameters that will just get added to Report.

This is the code i have so far to pass the HashMap with the parameters to the Report. But I am lost as there isnt really any good documentation or examples that I can find.

```
package print;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PrintCertificate  
{   
   public PrintCertificate(String output, String certType, String firstName, String lastName, String confirmDate, String pastorName)
   {
    if(certType=="rci_eng")
    {
        String fileName = "/RCI_Eng.jasper";
        output = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/";

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("FirstName",firstName);
        map.put("LastName",lastName);
        map.put("PastorName", pastorName);
        map.put("DateOfConfirmation", confirmDate);
        try
        {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, map);
            JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "test.docx");
            exporter.exportReport(print);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I know this is probably far from correct, but if someone can point me in the right direction of good documentation or examples, or point out what I've done wrong, it would be of great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Here is a brief description to use Jasper Report with your Java Application**

- **First you have to set database connection to the Report.**

[image]

- **Then you can design your SQL query for the report.**
  [image]
  You can add parameters to the SQL query in case you need to filter data through your query.Just add parameters using **New Parameter**  button and you can drag and drop parameters displaying inside the text area to your query.

In your report inspector you can see all the column names of our query under **Fields** category and all the parameters defined under **Parameters** category.
[image]

- **You can design a basic report like below**
  By dragging and dropping field names and parameters to your **Report Designer** you can design your report as you desire. **Title Band**(Your Title Here) , **Column Header Band**(Column Names) , **Detail Band**(Iterative Data here) and **Summary Band**(Like Grand_Total,Date,Issued By and chart elements can be added to this section) are enough for basic report.
  [image]
- Then you can declare **ReportGenarator** class to generate your
  report

  ```
  public class ReportGenarator {

  public static String OUT_PUT = "your_output_file_path/myreport.docx";
  public static String REPORT = "your_report_path/myreport.jrxml";

  public void genarateReport(String reportPath,
          Map<String, Object> map, Connection con) {
      try {

          JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(
                  ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(reportPath));
          JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map, con);
          JRDocxExporter export = new JRDocxExporter();
      export.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jp));
      export.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File(OUT_PUT)));
      SimpleDocxReportConfiguration config = new SimpleDocxReportConfiguration();
      export.setConfiguration(config);
      export.exportReport();
      } catch (JRException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();   
      }
  } }
  ```
- **You can generate your report by Pressing a button in your application.So that you have to include below code inside your button
  action event**

  ```
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
              map.put("headding", "REPORT FROM DATABASE CONNECTION");//parameter name should be like it was named inside your report.
              new ReportGenarator().genarateReport(
                      ReportGenarator.REPORT, map, your_DB_connction_reference_here);
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think i already had all of the report part done, but this ReportGenerator information is exactly what i was looking for!

If my .jrxml file is in the same package location as my java class would my REPORT look like this?    

REPORT = "myreport.jrxml";

Comment: Yes.But It is a good practice to separate your report files to a different package instead of putting them in same package with your class files.

Comment: This makes complete sense. We already do this with images, as we have a separate images folder.

Another question. Do i have to import the JRDocxExporter ?

Because i have the whole package imported: import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*; but its saying JRDocxExporter cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Yes.Otherwise it will be an error in your application `cannot find symbol`.
If you get an error with `REPORT = "myreport.jrxml";` then please add your package name in-front and try REPORT = "package_name/myreport.jrxml";

Comment: So all the errors are gone now.

The only difference between what i did, and your example is that I am only passing jr and map JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map); Because is used JasperSoft Studio to establish the JDBC connection. Or do i still need to pass a connection anyways?

Comment: You should have these imports

`import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleDocxReportConfiguration;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96396/discussion-between-webminer07-and-madushan-perera).