# Passing data from a Jtable to Ireport

Tags: java, jtable, jasper-reports

I have a jtable which is dynamically getting data. For an example, i have a jtable which loads all the employee information by search button click. Then user can filter data from those employees. From departments, Employee numbers etc.. I want to pass those filtered data into ireports. Not by taking data from the database. Only by taking data from the jtable. i wrote following code. but it shows errors.

```
try {
                DefaultTableModel df = ( DefaultTableModel ) jTable1.getModel();
                JRTableModelDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(df);
                String reportSource = "./Leave.jrxml";
                JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
                Map<String, object> params = new HashMap<String, object>();
                params.put("title1" , "title 1");
                JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, dataSource);
            } catch (JRException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LeaveManagementInfosystem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

it says "title 1" is not an object. I tried it again by not adding "". but same error is occurred. how can i get rid of this error.

Comment: Is this really how your code look like: "`Map<String, object>`"? Do you have class called `object` in your application?

Comment: Looks like `object`should read `Object` (capitalized).

Answer (score 2):

We will assume that that you have a **JTable** with 3 columns which are `s_id`,`name`,`age`.

[image]

In your jasper report you should create **fields** with same names according to your table columns.

[image]

```
<field name="s_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="age" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

You dont need to pass parameters to your jasper report.

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(
                    source);
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                    null, new JRTableModelDataSource(model));
  JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
```

Comment: Do i only need to add column names?

Comment: hope you got it correct. Do not hesitate to mark as the correct answer if it is useful.

Comment: it shows error that "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException"

Comment: Attribute 'uuid' is not allowed to appear in element 'jasperReport'. and this error coming

Comment: open the jrxml code and remove all the `uuid` attributes, save and reopen.

Comment: If still got the report path not found exception try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966181/how-to-pass-parameters-to-jasperreport-with-java-to-use-later-in-sql-query)

Comment: No now it says ,Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: sorry i didnt find the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

create parameters with same as column names bind the value with their fields
and add the params to query above java code works for me